# Converting R file to Stata with missing string values

Tags: r, stata

I am getting an error while converting R file into Stata format. I am able to convert the numbers into 
Stata file but when I include strings I get the following error:

```
library(foreign)
write.dta(newdata, "X.dta")

Error in write.dta(newdata, "X.dta") : 
  empty string is not valid in Stata's documented format
```

I have few strings like location, name etc. which have missing values which is probably causing this problem. Is there a way to handle this? .

Comment: Can you post example input data generating that error?

Comment: Just to be clear, if "empty string" is to be interpreted as ``""``, then Stata does allow it. In fact, it corresponds to missing observation for a string variable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've had this error many times before, and it's easy to reproduce:

```
library(foreign)
test <- data.frame(a = "", b = 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
write.dta(test, 'example.dta')
```

One solution is to use factor variables instead of character variables, e.g.,

```
for (colname in names(test)) {
  if (is.character(test[[colname]])) {
    test[[colname]] <- as.factor(test[[colname]])
  }
}
```

Another is to change the empty strings to something else and change them back in Stata.

This is purely a problem with `write.dta`, because Stata is perfectly fine with empty strings. But since `foreign` is frozen, there's not much you can do about that.

**Update:** (2015-12-04) A better solution is to use `write_dta` in the `haven` package:

```
library(haven)
test <- data.frame(a = "", b = 1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
write_dta(test, 'example.dta')
```

This way, Stata reads string variables properly as strings.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the great `readstata13` package (which kindly imports only the `Rcpp` package).

```
readstata13::save.dta13(mtcars, 'mtcars.dta')
```

The function allows to save already in *Stata 15/16 MP* file format (experimental), which is the next update after *Stata 13* format.

```
readstata13::save.dta13(mtcars, 'mtcars15.dta', version="15mp")
```

***Note:*** Of course, this also works with OP's data:

```
readstata13::save.dta13(data.frame(a="", b=1), 'my_data.dta')
```